# Unix egrep looks into folder information?

Tags: unix, grep

I am have a simple egrep command that searches through all the files in the current directory for lines that contain the word "error":

```
egrep -i "error" *
```

This command will also go through the sub-directories as well. Here is a sample of what the whole folder looks like:

```
/Logfile_20120630_030000_ID1.log
/Logfile_20120630_030001_ID2.log
/Logfile_20120630_030005_ID3.log
/subfolder/Logfile_20120630_031000_Errors_A3.log
/subfolder/Logfile_20120630_031001_Errors_A3.log
/subfolder/Logfile_20120630_031002_Errors_A3.log
/subfolder/Logfile_20120630_031003_Errors_A3.log
```

The logfiles at the top directory contain "error" lines. But the logfiles in the "subfolder" directory do not contain lines with "error". (only in the filename)

So the problem I am getting is that the egrep command seems to be looking at the information within the "subfolder". My result gets a chunk of what seems to be binary block, then the text lines that contain the word "error" from the top folder logfiles.

If I deleted all the files underneath "subfolder", but did not delete the folder itself, I get the exact same results.

So does Unix keep file history information inside a folder??

The problem was corrected by running:
find . -type f | egrep -i "error" *

But I still dont understand why it was a problem. I'm running C-shell on a SunOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
egrep -i error *
```

The `*` metacharacter matches ANY file name.  Directories are files, too.  `*` is expanded by the shell into any and all files in the current directory,  this is traditionally called globbing.

```
set noglob
```

turns off that behavior.  However, it is unlikely there are files named `*` in your directory, so in this example the command would find no files of any kind.  BTW - Do not create a file named `*` to test this, because files named `*` may cause all kinds of interesting and unwanted things to happen.  Think about what might happen when you tried to delete the file?  `rm '*'`  would be the right command, but if you or someone else did a `rm *` unthinkingly then you have problems...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw how egrep was treating the directory as a file. I was just curious what exactly keeps track of the history.

Comment: I also noticed that when you have a directory with files in it, and then delete all the files underneath it, the directory filesize does not change. I'm guessing this is the same historical information I'm referring to above. I would like to learn more about this how it works in Unix. I'm guessing its something with the inode pointers, but I thought those pointers were deleted when a file was deleted. ???

Comment: The files are indeed deleted (and the inodes freed if there are no more links); there is no dedicated file history information kept, it's just that the directory entries are only marked as free, while the names are not overwritten, so they remain in the directory file until the entries are reused.